# spring-data-neo4j query using dynamic key and dynamic value

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

**spring-data-neo4j** query using dynamic key and dynamic value,

like following code:

```
public interface NodeReposity extends Neo4jRepository<Node,Long> {
    @Query("MATCH(n:Node{{key}={value}})return n")
    Iterable<Node> queryByProperty(@Param("key")String key,@Param("value") String value);
}
```

But it says the {key} must be something like variable in string, such as `MATCH(n:Node{name={value}})return n`.Can't be {key}. But My property's key is dynamic like the value, how to implement it and is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: The query will be send "as it is" to the database and because cypher does only support placeholders for values, this will cause an error.

Slightly longer answer: When it comes to executing the **method** Spring Data Neo4j will look if it has already pre-processed the **query** and either process and cache it or just load it from the cache. This is done to improve the time it takes to execute the method from the application.
Pre-processing means SDN knows what parameters are in there and just adds the values in the right place when the **method** is called.
If SDN would provide more features for the query than cypher, the **query** would have to be processed every time the **method** gets called to create a new query that can be used with Neo4j.